# "TypeError at / argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath" in django ecommerce website

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-templates, posix

I was building an eCommerce website using Django and Vue.Js. There was no issue while I was hosting the website in localhost. But when I deployed my website on Heroku an error is showing up "TypeError at / argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath". Mainly an error in the jinja template.

## code:

```
{% for category in menu_categories %}
.. statements ..
{% endfor %}
```

> buckler-ecom.herokuapp.com
> [The link to the deployed site](https://buckler-ecom.herokuapp.com)

## settings.py

```
STRIPE_API_KEY_PUBLISHABLE = "secret"
STRIPE_API_KEY_HIDDEN = "secret"

RAZORPAY_API_KEY_PUBLISHABLE = "secret"
RAZORPAY_API_KEY_HIDDEN = "secret"

PAYPAL_API_KEY_PUBLISHABLE = "secret"
PAYPAL_API_KEY_HIDDEN = "secret"

import os

from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent


SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'buckler-ecom.herokuapp.com']

EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_PORT = 1025

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'cart'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'frontpage'

# Cart

SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 86400
CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'apps.cart',
    'apps.coupon',
    'apps.core',
    'apps.newsletter',
    'apps.order',
    'apps.store',
    'apps.userprofile'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'eCom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'apps.store.context_processors.menu_categories',
                'apps.cart.context_processors.cart'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'eCom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from apps.store.models import Product, Category

def frontpage(request):
    products = Product.objects.filter(is_featured=True)
    featured_categories = Category.objects.filter(is_featured=True)
    popular_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-num_visits')[0:4]
    recently_viewed_products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-last_visit')[0:4]

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'featured_categories': featured_categories,
        'popular_products': popular_products,
        'recently_viewed_products': recently_viewed_products
    }

    return render(request, 'frontpage.html', context)
```

Comment: This is not an error in your template.This is the error of the Pathlib. You have used Pathlib in your view, in which you have passed the argument, it is a PosixPath

Comment: If you show a dummy view of how you have used the Pathlib then i will understand the error.

Comment: Perhaps this error will be due to your settings.py file Because you have conf. the static file from there

Comment: wait I will share the settings.py

Comment: uploaded my settings.py file

Comment: Your settings.py are right i think there is something wrong with the views.Have you followed the path? Have you done it in your views then show it

Comment: I just showed my views.py

Comment: the thing is working fine in localhost but showing an error after deploying on heroku

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, tried this and it worked:

```
STATIC_ROOT=BASE_DIR.as_posix()+ "static"
```

the same for

```
MEDIA_ROOT=BASE_DIR.as_posix()+ "media"
```

also had to use the same workaround to:

```
DATABASES = {'defalut':{
....
'NAME': BASE_DIR.as_posix() +'db.sqlite3',
}
}
```

Comment: thanks. it works for me. just changed the sqlite directory as you mentioned above. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

try this i think this should work for you just replace your static and media url by this :

```
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [

    BASE_DIR / "static",
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR.parent / "static_cdn"

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT =  BASE_DIR / "media"
```

and no need to import os and try to use relative url for login,logout like this :

```
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/logout/'

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Comment: the problem remains.
http://buckler-ecom.herokuapp.com

Comment: check your db.sqlite3 location at heroku.

Comment: you din't set static root

Comment: TypeError at / argument 1 must be str, not PosixPath this error is came because of Pathlib

Comment: check this it is similar to your error and he solved his error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154269/typeerror-join-argument-must-be-str-or-bytes-not-posixpath

Comment: I will look forward to applying this set of codes. Let's see if that works!

Comment: maybe this code will help you to solve your problem (-:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.
After going through ample answers, the one below finally worked for me.

1. Make use of joinpath() function from pathlib library already imported.
2. convert the above result into string format by using the str() function.

```py
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('db.sqlite3')),
    }
}
```

Let us know if this works or not!